# Is it possible to change document type with JavaScript without page reload?

Tags: javascript

If I wanted to render whole page again with JavaScript, I would have to possibly change document type without page reloading. Is it possible to change document type with JavaScript or is only realistic choice to reload page and render new document type on server side?

Answer (score 4):

```
document.doctype;
//<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

var newDocType = document.implementation.createDocumentType( 'svg:svg', '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN', 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd' );

document.replaceChild( newDocType, document.doctype);

document.doctype;
//<!DOCTYPE svg:svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMImplementation.createDocumentType

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild

Please read the references carefully though, I personally cannot fathom any use case for this so I don't have personal experience using this.

Comment: Y U NO LINK DOM4 [replaceChild](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-node-replacechild), [createDocumentType](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-domimplementation-createdocumenttype)

Comment: @Raynos—probably because it isn't the current standard.

Comment: @RobG I believed DOM4 is supposed to be a living document in a similar fashion to WHATWG's HTML.

Comment: It may be intended to be a *living specification*. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to change document type with JavaScript...?

No. <strike>The DOCTYPE is not part of the DOM</strike> (was thinking of XML style sheet declarations).

#### EDIT

While you may be able to change the document's [DocumentType](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-412266927) (doctype) node, the result of doing so is unlikely to do anything useful or be reliable.

The current standard is the [DOM 3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/), where the definition of [document.doctype](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A31) says (in part):

> Note, however, that while some implementations may instantiate
>   different types of Document objects supporting additional features
>   … based on the
>   DocumentType specified at creation time, changing it afterwards is
>   very unlikely to result in a change of the features supported.

It also should be noted that [Interface DocumentType](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-412266927) is in the [Extended Interfaces: XML Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-E067D597) section, it is intended for XML documents and is not mandatory for, nor is it intended to be used with, HTML documents.

In the proposed DOM 4 Core standard, [section 5.1 Node Tree](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#node-tree) says that a doctype node is optional in a node tree.

If the intention is to change a document from say, **quirks** mode to **no–quirks** mode, in the DOM 4 draft there is the non—normative comment that:

> The mode is only ever changed from the default if the document is
>   created by the HTML parser, based on the presence, absence, or value
>   of the DOCTYPE string.

DOM 4 also assumes all documents to be XML by default unless the DOCTYPE states otherwise, that may take some time to filter into browsers in use.